# How do I create a button that inverts the y axis?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm working on an options menu in Unreal Engine 4, and I want there to be a button for inverting the y-axis of the mouse/controller. I've got the button set up, but now I'm not sure how to go about making the functionality for it. What's the best way to create blueprints for an invert axis button?

Answer (score 0):

The first way I see of doing this would be to have a boolean in your player controller that states if the Y axis should be inverted and add a branch after your Y axis input node and invert it here.

This way your button would just have to switch that boolean to control the inverted state of Y axis.

Comment: This _kind_ of makes sense; Idk how to put a boolean in a player controller but I suppose I could figure that out separately. More importantly though, what should the boolean do? What module is used to invert the axis?

Comment: In your player controller you should have an input yaw (if you use a UE4 template like third person template) in wich you could branch on a boolean to have 2 differents output (being the input or the input inverted)

Comment: I've figured out how to adjust the input yaw with blueprints, but I have no clue what to do to it to get what I want; could you be a little more specific? I get the logic branch part, but what comes after the logic branch? What nodes are used to change the yaw, and how are they supposed to change it?

Comment: I guess you could try like multiplying your input by -1 to get the inverted value and plug this value into your "add yaw input" node